# .play() not firing within directive using $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using *buzz* for my sound and very familiar with it's functionality.  However, myself and mentor cannot figure out why my sound file is not firing within my directive.

**My directive:**

```
(function() {
    function clockTimer($interval, $window, STOP_WATCH) {

        return {
            templateUrl: '/templates/directives/clock_timer.html',
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

                scope.STOP_WATCH = STOP_WATCH; //see constants in app.js
                scope.startButton = 'Start Work';
                scope.breakButton = 'Take Break';
                scope.onBreak = false;  //boolean for alternating displaying of work-time or break
                var mySound = new buzz.sound("/sounds/blue.mp3", {
                  formats: ['mp3'],
                  preload: true
                });

                // @desc initiates holder of completed work sessions.  Increments by 1 once timer hits 0
                var completedWorkSessions = 0;
                // @desc Holds state for $interval call
                var promise;

                scope.$watch('STOP_WATCH.totalWorkTime', function() {
                  if (scope.STOP_WATCH.totalWorkTime === 0) {
                    mySound.play();
                    console.log(mySound);
                    console.log("im listening");
                  }
                });
```

**My VIEW**

```
<section class="clock-container">
<div ng-show="!onBreak === true"> {{ STOP_WATCH.totalWorkTime | clockFormat }}
  <button ng-click="startStopButton(startButton)" ng-show="!onBreak === true">{{ startButton }}</button>
</div>
<div ng-hide="onBreak === false"> {{ STOP_WATCH.totalBreakTime | clockFormat }}
  <button ng-click="takeBreakButton(breakButton)">{{ breakButton }}</button>
</div>
</section>
```

Buzz library is included within my index, I've tried adding `scope` to the beginning of `mySound`, tested the .mp3 within a test application (which worked fine), and still cannot get the sound to play.

Here is my **console** which demonstrates that `$watch` is firing when its suppose to:

```
sound {sound: audio, volume: 80}
clockTimer.js:51 im listening
```

Any ideas or solutions?  I don't have any controllers and think I shouldn't need one since its firing successfully in the console?

Comment: I think the watch will only fire when the variable `STOP_WATCH.totalWorkTime` changes.  Is this happening when you play the sound?

Comment: correct.  Within my application, it only fires and runs the function when my count down clock reaches zero.  So it appears to be firing when it should.

Comment: You know your code better than anyone else.  Can you try using a debugger to see what is really happening?

Comment: I'm using atom, and not familiar with to many other debuggers.  I did create a small test app to prove my sound file work under the same conditions.  However, this test was only done within a static index.html with scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `formats: ['mp3'],` from the buzz Object.  You can either use `formats: ['mp3'],` or `.mp3`, but not both.